# Write a function that reverses the order of the words in a string?

Tags: java

Im reading the book "programming interviews exposed" and the following question was interesting to me:

> Write a function that reverses the order of the words in a string. For
>   example, your function should transform the string “Do or do not,
>   there is no try.” to “try. no is there not, do or Do”. Assume that all
>   words are space delimited and treat punctuation the same as letters.

this image was included to help with the design of the algorithm:

[image]

what is the most efficient way of implementing this in JAVA?

Comment: my code is a mess, too embarrassed to post it here.

Comment: if you are learning, i assume you should not be embarrassed about it?

Comment: @BluesRockAddict No, reverse at the word level.

Comment: I've used a StringBuilder, inside a nested loop, which gives O(n^2), I have a whiteboard interview test coming up so I'm just trying to prepare by using a pen and paper. wanted to see if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

```
final List<String> a = Arrays.asList("Do or do not, there is no try.".split("\\s+"));
Collections.reverse(a);
final Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(it.next());
while (it.hasNext()) { b.append(" "); b.append(it.next()); }
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: why do you use the final keyword here?

Comment: That's my style. I always use it. You get into that habit when a functional language is your first language. Benefit: better readability, peace of mind that a var is not there to be changed in the process, but only as a named intermediate result.

Comment: Have a plus for the iterator trick, going to have to see if I can adapt that for .net, never did like the two naff ways I was doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Split the words based on spaces.Put the words in a stack and pop the words when you reach the end of string.

```
 //push elements onto stack
 for(int k =0; k < strtest.length ; k++)
 {
      if(strtest[k]!=null)
      {
           stack.push(strtest[k]);
      }
 }
 StringBuffer b1 = new StringBuffer("");
 // pop and put in stringbuffer
 while(!stack.isEmpty())
 {
     b1 = b1.append(stack.pop());
     b1.append(" ");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hope this isn't for a homework assignment, but here's one way to do this:

```
String input = "piglet quantum";
String[] words = input.split(" ");
String result = "";
for(String word : words) {
  result = word + " " + result;
}
// This is to remove the extra space (sorry!)
result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
```

But this doesn't strictly follow the method described in the image.  They want you to treat the words as arrays, so they would probably have you using `substring()` and `charAt()` to handle this.

Comment: That would add an extra space and the end of the word.

Comment: In Java it would be pretty stupid to start messing with substring and charAt since we have that high level method called split. This is how I would've done this as well, I'm voting for your answer. :)

Comment: Aye but given you knew Java why wouldn't you use split, and then reverse the array. If some one did it with charAt() and substring(), you'd have to say they were at best ignorant....

Comment: @maress Hardly, unless you know for a fact that split is internally O(n^2) for some strange reason?

Comment: More to the point do you care if it is or not. We're writing applications not trying to pass a CS exam.

Comment: @Tony Well, the original poster did ask for "the most efficient way" of doing this, and the algorithm processing time classification is one way of measuring efficiency. So I'd just like to hear why maress thinks that this solution is inefficient.

Comment: The string concat in the loop is really unefficient. A StringBuilder would be more appropriate

Comment: My measure of efficiency, is how much effort does it require to change it, coz change is a given. The premature optimisation implied by this sort of question just does me in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very straightforward way to do it:

```
String theInput = "Do or do not, there is no try.”;

String[] wordArray = theInput.split(" ");
String[] reverseWordArray = new String[wordArray.length];

int j = 0;
for (int i = wordArray.length; i > 0; i --) {
  reverseWordArray[j++] = wordArray[i-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a low(-er) level way (I think):

```
String in = "piglet quantum";
String out = "";

for(int i = in.length()-1; i >= 0; i+=0) {
  out += in.substring(in.lastIndexOf(" ", i-1), i)+" ";
  i = in.lastIndexOf(" ", i-1);
}

out.substring(0, out.length()-1);
```

Like I said, not sure if this works or not, but I think it will.

I don't know what to do for the last condition in the `for` if anyone has a suggestion. It shouldn't do anything.

Comment: String index out of range: -1 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

A [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) is also an option:

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class ReverseWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "piglet quantum";
        BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
        boundary.setText(source);
        int end = boundary.last();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int start = boundary.previous(); start != BreakIterator.DONE; end = start, start = boundary.previous()) {
            sb.append(source.substring(start, end));
        }
        String reversed = sb.toString();
        System.err.println("'" + reversed + "'");
    }
}
```

And it outputs:

> 'quantum piglet'